# Как выбрать на Android с DUAL-SIM поддержкой, с какой карточки сделать вызов?

Tags: android

Моя программа на данный момент рассчитана для односимочных телефонов, в неё я посылаю запрос способом стартования нового **Activity**:
**startActivity(new Intent(«android.intent.action.CALL», Uri.parse(«tel:» + phoneNumber)))**
Но встал вопрос, как это сделать, если у телефона 2 симки?

Answer (score 4):

Я бы сделал так:

1. Проверка на колличество сим:

   TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);
   boolean isDualSIM = telephonyInfo.isDualSIM();
2. Если дуал сим, показал бы пользователю любой диалог для выбора, с какой симки сделать вызов.
3. В зависимости от выбора осуществил вызов

   intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 0); // Сим 1
   intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 1);// Сим 2

Класс TelephonyInfo:

```
public final class TelephonyInfo {

private static TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo;
private String imeiSIM1;
private String imeiSIM2;
private boolean isSIM1Ready;
private boolean isSIM2Ready;

public String getImeiSIM1() {
    return imeiSIM1;
}

/*public static void setImeiSIM1(String imeiSIM1) {
    TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = imeiSIM1;
}*/

public String getImeiSIM2() {
    return imeiSIM2;
}

/*public static void setImeiSIM2(String imeiSIM2) {
    TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = imeiSIM2;
}*/

public boolean isSIM1Ready() {
    return isSIM1Ready;
}

/*public static void setSIM1Ready(boolean isSIM1Ready) {
    TelephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = isSIM1Ready;
}*/

public boolean isSIM2Ready() {
    return isSIM2Ready;
}

/*public static void setSIM2Ready(boolean isSIM2Ready) {
    TelephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = isSIM2Ready;
}*/

public boolean isDualSIM() {
    return imeiSIM2 != null;
}

private TelephonyInfo() {
}

public static TelephonyInfo getInstance(Context context){

    if(telephonyInfo == null) {

        telephonyInfo = new TelephonyInfo();

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

        telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();;
        telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = null;

        try {
            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 0);
            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 1);
        } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            try {
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 0);
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;
        telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = false;

        try {
            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 0);
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 1);
        } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return telephonyInfo;
}

private static String getDeviceIdBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

    String imei = null;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try{

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

        if(ob_phone != null){
            imei = ob_phone.toString();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
    }

    return imei;
}

private static  boolean getSIMStateBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

    boolean isReady = false;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try{

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimStateGemini = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        Object ob_phone = getSimStateGemini.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

        if(ob_phone != null){
            int simState = Integer.parseInt(ob_phone.toString());
            if(simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){
                isReady = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
    }

    return isReady;
}

private static class GeminiMethodNotFoundException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -996812356902545308L;

    public GeminiMethodNotFoundException(String info) {
        super(info);
    }
}
}
```

**Обновление**

Для проверки дуал сим:

```
public boolean isDualSIM() {
    return imeiSIM2 != null && imeiSIM1 != null;
}
```

Для звонка попробуйте

```
intent.putExtra("simSlot", 1);
```

Comment: Обязательно проверю вашу информацию завтра и скажу о результате.

Comment: Я проверил ваш код, но, к сожалению, он не позволил мне делать звонки с разных карточек, используя ваш метод:

    intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 0); // Сим 1
    intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 1);// Сим 2

Этим методом получилось лишь обнаружить, что телефон имеет несколько сим. К тому же он показал на односимочном телефоне(LG G), что он поддерживает dual-sim, хотя таковой поддержки там нету, а показал он это потому, что в коде проверка на двусимочность произмодится по наличию IMAI 2. В данном телефоне как раз имелся IMAI 2, но не было IMAI 1.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Тоже не сработало. В общем, ерунда всё это, пока Google не выпустит полноценное API для dul-sim, но скорее всего такого никогда не будет...