# Как определить код оператора на второй сим карте android?

Tags: java, android-sdk, android, imei

Есть проект который состоит из:

```java
package com.examp.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);

        String imeiSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM1();
        String imeiSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM2();

        String OperatorNameSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getOperatorCodeSIM1();
        String OperatorNameSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getOperatorCodeSIM2();

        boolean isSIM1Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready();
        boolean isSIM2Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready();

        boolean isDualSIM = telephonyInfo.isDualSIM();

        TextView TextView_TEST = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_TEST);

        TextView_TEST.setText(" IME1 : " + imeiSIM1 + " \n " + "IME2 : " + imeiSIM2 + " \n " + "IS DUAL SIM : " + isDualSIM + " \n " + "IS SIM1 READY : " + isSIM1Ready + " \n " + "IS SIM2 READY : " + isSIM2Ready + " \n " + "MNC_SIM1 : " + OperatorNameSIM1 + " \n " + "MNC_SIM2 : " + OperatorNameSIM2 + " ");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Есть класс: TelephonyInfo

```java
package com.examp.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public final class TelephonyInfo {

    private static TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo;
    private String imeiSIM1;
    private String imeiSIM2;

    private String OperatorCodeSIM1;
    private String OperatorCodeSIM2;

    private boolean isSIM1Ready;
    private boolean isSIM2Ready;

    public String getImeiSIM1() {
        return imeiSIM1;
    }

/*public static void setImeiSIM1(String imeiSIM1) {
    TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = imeiSIM1;
}*/

    public String getImeiSIM2() {
        return imeiSIM2;
    }

/*public static void setImeiSIM2(String imeiSIM2) {
    TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = imeiSIM2;
}*/

    public String getOperatorCodeSIM1() {
        return OperatorCodeSIM1;
    }

    public String getOperatorCodeSIM2() {
        return OperatorCodeSIM2;
    }

/* Отредактировать данный комент
public void setOperatorCode(String OperatorCode) {
OperatorCode = OperatorCode;
}*/

    public boolean isSIM1Ready() {
        return isSIM1Ready;
    }

/*public static void setSIM1Ready(boolean isSIM1Ready) {
    TelephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = isSIM1Ready;
}*/

    public boolean isSIM2Ready() {
        return isSIM2Ready;
    }

/*public static void setSIM2Ready(boolean isSIM2Ready) {
    TelephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = isSIM2Ready;
}*/

    public boolean isDualSIM() {
        return imeiSIM2 != null;
    }

    private TelephonyInfo() {
    }

    public static TelephonyInfo getInstance(Context context){

        if(telephonyInfo == null) {

            telephonyInfo = new TelephonyInfo();

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();;
            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = null;

            telephonyInfo.OperatorCodeSIM1 = telephonyManager.getSimOperator();;
            telephonyInfo.OperatorCodeSIM2 = null;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    try {
                        telephonyInfo.OperatorCodeSIM1= getSimOperatorBySlot(context, "getSimOperator",0);
                        telephonyInfo.OperatorCodeSIM2= getSimOperatorBySlot(context, "getSimOperator",1);
                    }catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = false;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return telephonyInfo;
    }

    private static String getDeviceIdBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

        String imei = null;

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try{

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

            if(ob_phone != null){
                imei = ob_phone.toString();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }

        return imei;
    }

    private static  boolean getSIMStateBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

        boolean isReady = false;

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try{

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimStateGemini = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimStateGemini.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

            if(ob_phone != null){
                int simState = Integer.parseInt(ob_phone.toString());
                if(simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){
                    isReady = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }

        return isReady;
    }

    private static String getSimOperatorBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID)
            throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {
        String OperatorCode = null;
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try {

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);
            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);
            if (ob_phone != null) {
                OperatorCode = ob_phone.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }
        return OperatorCode;
    }


    private static class GeminiMethodNotFoundException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -996812356902545308L;

        public GeminiMethodNotFoundException(String info) {
            super(info);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и Активити xml:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView_TEST" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ну и стандартный манифест содержащий только

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Вся проблема в том, что `MNC` отображается только первой сим-карты, даже если ее в настройках выключить `МНС` номер отображает, а вот симреди-фолс пишет.

Если первую симку вынуть, а оставить только СИМ2 то отображает МНС номер второй сим-карты.

**Собственно как сделать так чтобы отображался номер как первой так и второй симки?**

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/369490/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android-%D1%81-dual-sim-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2?answertab=active#tab-top) оригинал, а [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689989/how-to-get-simoperator-for-a-dual-sim-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top) уже с определением MNC

Сейчас у меня это все выглядит примерно так с двумя сим-картами:
[image: Dual Sim MNC code & imei]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424914/14197) сами себе ответили, что у MTK есть официальный API и при этом почему-то этим API не воспользовались.

Могу посоветовать кроме метода `getSimOperatorBySlot(context, "getSimOperator",1);` поискать ещё `getSimOperatorBySlot(context, "getSimOperatorGemini",1);` Насколько я помню, у MTK все эти методы с суффиксом gemini. У вас в коде все методы сначала проверяются с ним, а потом без него, кроме нужного вам `getSimOperator`.

Comment: Спасибо, что то упустил данный момент, так реально getSimOperatorGemini если верить вот этим сорцям - https://goo.gl/3Ll4J8.